Group items (+ nested groups) in details list on selection
I'm using Fluent UI details list that contains a large number of items.
On selecting 2 or more items

create a new group let's call (GroupA)
display selected items in GroupA
display remaining items outside of group & within the list (UnelectedGroup).

On selecting 2 or more items in GroupA

display selected items in a nested group let's call (GroupA1)
display unselected items outside of nested group GroupA1 but within GroupA
display remaining items outside of group (UnelectedGroup)

On selecting 2 or more items outside of Groups (in this case, outside of GroupA):

create a new group let's call (GroupB)
display selected items in GroupB
display remaining items outside of groups & within the list (UnelectedGroup).

And this should go on.
So,

if 2 or more items are selected from the list, Create a new group & display selected items
if 2 or more items are selected from inside a Group, create nested group.

Items can be selected in any order:
Here is the code I've tried so far:
const { DetailsList, DetailsListLayoutMode, type, IComboBoxOption, IComboBoxStyles, Selection, ThemeProvider, initializeIcons, IGroup, ActionButton } = window.FluentUIReact;

initializeIcons();

const initialItems = [
  { key: 'name', name: '=', value: 'a', operator: 'or' },
  { key: 'name', name: '=', value: 'b', operator: 'or' },
  { key: 'name', name: '=', value: 'c', operator: 'or' },
  { key: 'name', name: '=', value: 'd', operator: 'or' },
  { key: 'name', name: '=', value: 'e', operator: 'or' },
  { key: 'name', name: '=', value: 'f', operator: 'or' } 
];

 const columns = [
    {
      key: 'key',
      name: 'Key',
      fieldName: 'key',
      minWidth: 200,
      maxWidth: 200,
      isResizable: false
    },
    {
      key: 'name',
      name: 'Equal',
      fieldName: 'name',
      minWidth: 200,
      maxWidth: 200,
      isResizable: false
    },
    {
      key: 'value',
      name: 'Value',
      fieldName: 'value',
      minWidth: 200,
      maxWidth: 200,
      isResizable: false
    },
    {
      key: 'operator',
      name: 'And/Or',
      fieldName: 'operator',
      minWidth: 200,
      maxWidth: 200,
      isResizable: true
    },
    {
      key: 'remove',
      name: '',
      fieldName: 'remove',
      minWidth: 200,
      maxWidth: 200,
      isResizable: true
    }
  ];


const DetailsListExample: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  
   const [selectedIndices, setSelectedIndices] =     React.useState<number[]>([]);
    const [isGroupingEnabled, setIsGroupingEnabled] = React.useState(false);
  const [handleGrouping, setHandleGrouping] = React.useState(false);
  
  const handleSelectionChanged = () => {
    console.log("length", selection.getSelectedIndices().length);
    setSelectedIndices(selection.getSelectedIndices());
    
  };
  
   const [selection] = React.useState(() => new Selection({
    onSelectionChanged: handleSelectionChanged
  }));
  
  function getGroupItemIndices(group: IGroup, baseIndex = 0): number[] {
  let indices: number[] = [];
  const startIndex = baseIndex + group.startIndex;
  const endIndex = startIndex + group.count;
  for (let i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
    indices.push(i);
  }

  if (group.children && group.children.length > 0) {
    for (let childGroup of group.children) {
      const childIndices = getGroupItemIndices(childGroup, startIndex);
      indices = indices.concat(childIndices);
    }
  }
  return indices;
}
  
  function getUnselectedGroupIndices(group: IGroup, selectedIndices: number[]): number[] {  
  const groupIndices = getGroupItemIndices(group);
  const unselectedIndices = groupIndices.filter(index => !selectedIndices.includes(index));
  return unselectedIndices;
}

  
  const [ items, setItems ] = React.useState(initialItems);
  const [groups, setGroups] = React.useState<IGroup[]>([]);
 
   const onGroupClick = () => {
    if (groups.length === 0) {
      setHandleGrouping(true);
      const selectedItems = selectedIndices.map(index => items[index]);
      const remainingItems = items.filter((_, index) => !selectedIndices.includes(index));
      const updatedItems = [...remainingItems, ...selectedItems];
      const startIndex = remainingItems.length;
      const selectedItemsLength = selectedItems.length;
      const group = createGroupFromSelectedIndices(startIndex, selectedItemsLength, false);
      setItems(updatedItems);
      setIsGroupingEnabled(updatedItems.length > 1);
      setGroups(group);
      setSelectedIndices([]);
      selection.setAllSelected(false);
    }
    else {
      const updatedGroups: IGroup[] = [];
      groups.forEach(group => {
        const isNestingGroup = selectedIndices.every(index =>
            index >= group.startIndex && index < group.startIndex + group.count
        );
        if (isNestingGroup) {
          const selectedItemsInGroup = selectedIndices.map(index => items[index]);
          const remainingItemsInGroup = items.filter((_, index) => !selectedIndices.includes(index));
          const updatedItems = [...remainingItemsInGroup, ...selectedItemsInGroup];
          setItems(updatedItems);
          let de = getUnselectedGroupIndices(group, selectedIndices);
          const firstGroup: IGroup = {
              key: 'selectedGroup',
              name: '',
              startIndex: group.startIndex,
              count: de.length,
          };
          console.log("first group: startIndex", group.startIndex);
          console.log("first group: count", de.length);
          const nestedGroup = {
              key: `nested-${group.key}`,
              name: 'Grouped attributes',
              startIndex: group.startIndex + de.length,
              count: selectedItemsInGroup.length,
              isNested: true
          };
          console.log("nested group: startIndex",  group.startIndex + de.length);
          console.log("nested group: count", selectedItemsInGroup.length);
          if (!group.children) group.children = [];
          group.children.push(firstGroup);
          group.children.push(nestedGroup);
        }
        updatedGroups.push(group);
      });
      setGroups(updatedGroups);
    }
    setSelectedIndices([]);
    selection.setAllSelected(false);
  };
  
  const onUngroupClick = () => {  
  setIsGroupingEnabled(false);
  setHandleGrouping(false);
  setGroups([]); 
};
  
 const createGroupFromSelectedIndices = (startIndex: number, selectedItemsLength: number): IGroup[] => {
  if (selectedIndices.length === 0) return [];
  const firstGroup: IGroup = {
    key: 'selectedGroup',
    name: 'Grouped attributes',
    startIndex: startIndex,
    count: selectedItemsLength,
  };

  const unselectedGroup: IGroup = {
    key: 'unselectedGroup',
    name: 'Unselected Items Group',
    startIndex: 0,
    count: startIndex,
  };

  console.log("firstGroup", firstGroup);
  return [firstGroup, unselectedGroup];
};
  
  return (
    <div>
    {selectedIndices.length > 1 && (
            <ActionButton iconProps={{ iconName: 'GroupObject' }} onClick={onGroupClick}>
              Group
            </ActionButton>
      )}    
      {groups.length > 0 && groups[0].count > 1 && (
            <ActionButton iconProps={{ iconName: 'GroupObject' }} onClick={onUngroupClick}>
              Ungroup
            </ActionButton>
          )}
      <DetailsList
          setKey="items"
          items={items}          
groups={isGroupingEnabled && handleGrouping ? groups : undefined}
          columns={columns}
          selection={selection}
          selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}       
          layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.justified}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const DetailsListExampleWrapper = () => <ThemeProvider><DetailsListExample /></ThemeProvider>;
ReactDOM.render(<DetailsListExampleWrapper />, document.getElementById('content'))

This is not creating groups as expected. What am I missing?
